Understanding the motivation of a step in a proof
I need help understanding the proof of a divisibility problem I was trying, it is not that I do not understand the steps of the proof, but rather I'm having a hard time understanding the motivation of the steps in the proof.
The problem states:

Given $n$ and $k$ integers such that $2^n>k>1$ prove that $3^n$ does not divide $k^n-1$

Solution:
Suppose FTSOC that $3^n|k^n-1$, then $gcd(3,k)=1$ then $3|k^2-1$ (how?). Therefore we have that $3|(k+1)(k-1)$
Let $p$ be such that $3^p$ divides $k^2-1$ and $3^{p+1}$ does not divide $k^2-1$. Then we have that $3^p|(k-1)(k+1)$, then $3^p$ divides one of the numbers $k-1$ or $k+1$ and is coprime with each other (why?), also $3^p \leq k+1$
Since $k+1 \leq 2^n$ then we have that $3^p\leq 2^n$ where $n < p$.
Now this is the part that I don't think it would have ever occurred to me. What is the motivation for considering such an idea.
Lemma
We consider all $r \ge 0$ such that $3^{p+r}$ divides $k^{2 \cdot 3^r}-1$ and $3^{p+r+1}$ does not divide $k^{2 \cdot 3^r}-1$.
For $r=0$ is clear from the definition of $p$.
Suppose that it is true for some $j \leq r$ then we consider $j=1 +r$. By the induction hypothesis we have that $k^{2 \cdot 3^r}-1= 3^{p+r}x$ with gcd $(3,x) = 1$ (why is this needed? what could happen if we don't assume that) then
\begin{align} k^{2 \cdot 3^{r+1}}-1={(k^{2 \cdot 3^r})}^3-1= (k^{2 \cdot 3^r}-1)(k^{4\cdot 3^{r}}+k^{2 \cdot 3^r}+1) \end{align}
\begin{align} = 3^{p+r+1}x(3^{2(p+r)-1}x^2+3^{p+r}x+1) \end{align}
And since $x(3^{2(p+r)-1}x^2+3^{p+r}x+1)$ is coprime with 3, then the induction is complete.
\begin{align} Q.E.D \end{align}
Let $j_0$ be the smallest positive integers such that $3^n|k^{j_0}-1$ and we have that $j_0 \leq n$, since we are supposing that $3^n|k^{n}-1$. Using our lemma $3^n=3^{p+(n-p)}$ divides $k^{2 \cdot 3^{n+p}}-1$ and $3^{n+1}$ does not divide $k^{2 \cdot 3^{n+p}}-1$. Then we have $j_o \leq 2 \cdot 3^{n-p}$.
We consider $u,v$ such that $2 \cdot 3^{n-p}= uj_o + v$ with $0 \leq v < j$.
Then we have that.
\begin{align} 3^n | k^{uj_o+v}-1= (k^{j_0})^uk^v-1 \end{align}
with $k^{j_0}=3^n \cdot m +1 $ for a certain integer $m$. Then
\begin{align} (k^{j_0})^uk^v-1=(3^n \cdot m +1)^uk^v-1= 3 \cdot m^{\prime}+k^v-1  \end{align}, where
\begin{align}3^n | k^{v}-1 \end{align}
Since $0 \leq v < j$, then  $v=0$, since $j_o$ is the minimum positive integer such that $3^n | k^{j_o}-1$. Then $j_0| 2\cdot 3^{n-p}$ then we can conclude that $j_0=2^i\cdot 3^s$, with $0 \leq i \leq 1$  and $
0 \leq s \leq n-p$. Therefore $j_0=3^s$ or $j_0=2\cdot 3^s$. In either case we have that.
\begin{align}3^n | k^{2\cdot 3^{s}}-1 \end{align}
From our lemma it follow that $s\geq n-p$. Therefore $3^{n-p}| j_0$.
Since we have that $j_o \leq n$ , we have that $3^{n-p} \leq n$, which is the same to
\begin{align} \frac{3^n}{n} \leq 3^p \end{align}
\begin{align} 2^n \leq  \frac{3^n}{n}-1 \leq 3^p-1\leq k \end{align}
Which contradicts our initial condition.
I could follow most of the proof but honestly I don't think I could have come up with it on my own. A more general question is what heuristics or tips are there to extract the motivation from terse or unmotivated answers? for example in this problem I spent hours trying the problem plugging numbers and trying to use basic divisibilty theorems but I never would have thought of considering an exponent such that p is the highest exponent that divides an expression and p+1 does not. Or the next step where $3^{p+r}$ divides $k^{2 \cdot 3^r}-1$ and $3^{p+r+1}$ does not divide $k^{2 \cdot 3^r}-1$. This part is even more elusive to me. Hopefully someone can explain me at least in this problem how could I have thought of those steps that seem to appear from nowhere.

What is "FTSOC"?

$\gcd(3,k) = 1$ means $k \equiv \pm 1\bmod 3$ If it is $\equiv 1$, then $3$ divides $k-1$ and if it is $\equiv -1$, then $3$ divides $k+1$. But how does this imply $k^p \mid (k^2+1)(k^2 - 1)$ when you haven't even defined a value for $p$ yet?

FTSOC means for the sake of contradiction.
Oh ok, I got it. However I don’t know where you got $(k^2-1)(k^2+1)$.
$p$ is just a positive integer.

Where I got it was straight from your post! "Therefore we have that $k^p\mid(k^2+1)(k^2-1)$". I see no justification for this statement. And what do you mean "$p$ is just a positive integer"? Are claiming this statement holds for any $p$? Are claiming it holds for some particular $p$. You just drop in a new variable without any information and make a claim that it satisfies without anything to base that claim on. Similarly later you start talking about "the induction hypothesis" when you haven't introduced any induction. It doesn't make any sense.

I'm sorry for the quality of the post. Seems that this problem is way out of my league. I'll post the solution just as is in the book, hopefully it is clearer. Btw The expression $(k^2-1)(k^2+1)$ was a typo.

+1 to the posted question, which I found to be well thought out and well presented.

The $k^p|(k+1)(k-1)$ which remains in the first paragraph of the solution is a misprint for $3^p|(k+1)(k-1)$.

@user2661923 - yes, it is much improved after the edit.

As for your second small question, From the first paragraph and since $3$ is prime, it divides one of $k-1$ and $k+1$. But it cannot divide both, since that would imply that it also divides their difference $2$. So if $3^p \mid (k-1)(k+1)$, all of the $3$s have to divide the same factor, since the other is not divisible by $3$ (it should read "and is coprime with the other", not "each other").

As a generic answer to your main question, what motivates a lot of odd concepts in proofs is a lot of exploration and hard work. This idea might not come to mind in your first thoughts about the problem, but after hours or even days of trying different things and just generally exploring the problem, you start to understand exactly where the most difficult issues appear, and hone in your attention to those areas. Once you finally break through, you throw away all the false starts and useless concepts you explored, and only write down the thing that actually worked.

There are several reasons why steps may seem unmotivated.
One of the most common is that problems are often solved by finding ways to reduce a problem to something simpler (which may just mean the same statement with smaller numbers). After some simplification, you have derived at something that remains to be proven, and the steps required to prove this may then appear well motivated. However, it is not uncommon to then present the solution in the opposite order, which is the order of the implications of the proof, in which case the motivation may be less apparent.
Another thing is that there may be general results, sometimes already known to those with experience in solving similar problems, which may be clearer if presented as a general result than in the form of the special case in which it is being applied.
One such example is that if $x=1+3^qm$ with $q\ge1$, then $x^3=1+3^{q+1}m'$ where $m'=m+3^qm^2+3^{2q-1}m^3$. What's more, if $q$ is the exact number of times 3 divides $x-1$, ie $m$ is not divisible by 3, then $m'$ is not divisible by 3 either, and so $x^3-1$ is divisible by 3 exactly $q+1$ times. Repeat this $r$ times, and you find that $x^{3^r}-1$ is divisible by 3 exactly $q+r$ times. You can even go one step further and show that the number of times 3 divides $x^n-1$ is equal to $q+r$ where $r$ is the number of times 3 divides $n$.
For an even more general result, the 3s could be replaced with some other number.
Since we have a problem involving how many times 3 divides $k^n-1$, this type of lemma might be expected to come in handy. The concept of how many times 3 divides some number may also be useful, as opposed to thinking in terms of divisibility by a particular power of $3$.
It is also worth pointing out that $3^{q+r}\mid x^r-1$ is the same as saying that $x^r\equiv1\pmod{3^{q+r}}$, but thinking in terms of modular arithmetic can be a lot simpler than thinking in terms of differences being divisible by that modulus.
There are already explanations in the comments on why $k^2-1$ is divisible by 3. However, the core is that $k$ is not a multiple of 3, so either $k-1$ or $k+1$ must be: $k^2-1$ is just the product of these two. Performing the proof in terms of $k^2-1$ avoids having to deal with two different cases, but makes the proof a bit harder to read. Instead, you could first assume $3\mid k-1$, and deal with the other case later: the proof will actually be the same, just replace $k$ with $-k$ as $3\mid k+1$ is the same as $3\mid (-k)-1$.
As mentioned above, instead of just starting with $3\mid k-1$ (or $3\mid k+1$), we want to look at how many times 3 divides $k-1$: ie 3 divides $k-1$ exactly $p$ times when $3^p\mid k-1$ but $3^{p+1}\nmid k-1$. So we can write $k=1+3^pm_0$ where $m_0$ is not divisible by 3. By the above result, this makes $k^3=1+3^{p+1}m_1$, and repeating this gives us $k^{3^r}=1+3^{p+r}m_r$, again with all the $m_i$ not divisible by 3.
Since there are no particular restrictions on the $n$ in the problem, it is natural to start off by asking how many times 3 divides $k^n-1$ for different values of $n$. We know from the previous paragraph that if $n=3^r$, then $3^{p+r}\mid k^{3^r}-1$. If $n=3^rs$ for some $s$ that is not divisible by 3, ie 3 divides $n$ exactly $r$ times, we can show that $k^n-1$ is still divisible by 3 exactly $p+r$ times. The are many ways to show this. We know that $k^{3^r}=1+3^{p+r}m_r$, and raising this to the $s$'th power will give a result on the form $1+3^{p+r}sm_r+\text{higher powers of 3}$, so $k^{3^rs}-1$ is still divisible by 3 exactly $p+r$ time.
Note that so far most of the results are general, except for the number 3 which could have been replaced by any other number. Now for the specifics of this particular problem.
From the above, we know that the number of times $k^n-1$ is divisible by 3 is determined by the number of times $n$ is divisible by 3. If $n=3^ua$, then $k^n-1$ is divisible by 3 exactly $p+u$ times. The assumption is that $k^n-1$ should be divisible by $3^n$, which requires $n\le p+u$.
So, now we have $1<k<2^n$, $3^p\le k+1$ (in order to also handle the $3\mid k+1$ case), and $n\le p+u$. We also note that $3^u\le n$ since $n=3^ua$. So now we can combine all these:
$$
3^n\le 3^{p+u}=3^p\cdot 3^u\le (k+1)\cdot n\le n2^n
$$
which is only possible if $n<3$. The cases $n=1,2$ we can check manually.
The final part here was simply about accumulating enough bounds on $n$, $k$, $p$, and $u$ to restrict the problem to a finite number of possible cases to test.
For someone with a bit of experience with this type of problems who are familiar with the general results described above, it is this last part that constitutes the actual work. Often the problem is that you manage to put various bounds on the variables, but are left with one that is unbounded. My guess is that the requirement $k<2^n$ was put in place exactly to provide this final bound.
Of course, starting from scratch, if the above results and techniques are completely unfamiliar, will be tough. Taking the time to work through these lemmas a few times, may be useful next time you come across a similar problem. but knowing them is usually not enough: you need to understand when to use them, when they help simplify the problem, and may still end up with a tricky bit at the end.

In the first part of the solution where it states $3^n| k^n-1$ then $gcd(3,k)=1$ ,I reasoned as follows "  $3^n| k^n-1$ can be written as $k^n- 3^n \cdot m=1 $ then any number that divides $k^n$ and $3^n$ must also divide the right side but the only divisor of 1 is 1 therefore  $gcd(k,3)=1$". Is this reasoing correct? Just want to be sure.

@Ruben: Yes, that looks right.
